# Get pivot data & vlookup with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I have the following pivot table:

| ID | Name | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Red | 1 |
| 123 | Black | 2 |
| 123 | White | 3 |
| 124 | Black | 1 |
| 124 | White | 2 |
| 124 | Red | 3 |

Considering two conditions: ID&ranking I would like to look into the pivot table and retrieve the name. For example, for ID 123 & Ranking 2 I would like to see the name Black as result.

Any hint to write the formula in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a standard FILTER function and multiply the two criteria to get your filter list

```
=FILTER(B1:B7,(A1:A7=123)*(C1:C7=2))
```